# Java Iterators and Lists - add to 3rd list

Tags: java, list, iterator, addition

I have two LinkedList and I want to add the Integeres from both into a third List. I'm trying to add the first element from the first list, then the first element from the second list etc.

I need the final output to be

```
[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10, 11, 12].
```

but I keep getting

```
[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10].
```

How do I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
public class Ex11_2_alternate {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<>();

    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5));
    list2.addAll(Arrays.asList(6,7,8,9,10,11,12));

    alternate(list,list2);

}
private static void alternate(List<Integer> list, List<Integer> list2) {

    List<Integer> list3 = new LinkedList<>();

    Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();
    Iterator<Integer> itr2 = list2.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext() & itr2.hasNext()) {
        int element = itr.next();
        int element2 = itr2.next();

        if ((element | element2) != 0) {
            list3.add(element);
            list3.add(element2);
        }


      }
    System.out.println("After ... : " + list3);
   }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The while loop in your progam does not work the way you think it does.

`&` will evaluate to `true` when all operands are `true`. Which means, in this case, your while loop will run until one of the two iterators does not have a next element! Since one of your lists is shorter than the other one, that means not everything from the second list will be added to the third!

If you replace the "and" with an "or" (`||`) though you will get an exception. Now your while loop tries to run until both lists are out of elements. One of them will run out before the other though, so the you're trying to get more elements out of the shorter list than it actually has!

To fix that problem you will have to check if there are more elements inside the loop again:

```
while(itr.hasNext() || itr2.hasNext()) {
    if(itr.hasNext()) {
        int element = itr.next();
        list3.add(element);
    }
    if(itr2.hasNext()) {
        int element = itr2.next();
        list3.add(element);
    }
}
```

P.S.: Besides that, you should use the logical "and" and "or" operators (`&&` and `||`) instead of the binary ones, if you just want to check conditions and not actual binary math. Most of the time they behave the same way, but sometimes they could produce unintended results.

Comment: Awesome. That worked for me. 

I just can't understand how it works. We have two while-loops. 
I can understand that it adds the integers to list3 - but I can't get a hold on how it does it in the correct order. 

Because, in the first while-loop it would add all values from list to list3... When it has finished doing that, it moves to the 2nd while-loop where it will add the values to list3 after all the values from list.


Can't understand how it can jump between the two while loops.

Comment: I edited my answer so that the values would alternate, since I missed that requirement when I first read your question. With this one while loop it should work now.

Answer (score 3):

Your method alternate has an & in the while, if you change it and you put an or and you look inside the while if any of it is null:

```
     private static void alternate (List<Integer> list, List<Integer> list2) {

        List<Integer> list3 = new LinkedList<>();

        Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();
        Iterator<Integer> itr2 = list2.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext() || itr2.hasNext()) {
            if (itr.hasNext()) {
                int element = itr.next();
                list3.add(element);
            }
            if (itr2.hasNext()) {
                int element2 = itr2.next();
                list3.add(element2);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After: " + list3);
    }
```

The result is:

```
After: [1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (itr.hasNext() & itr2.hasNext())
```

You are advancing as long as **both** have a next element. What if one is longer? Your while will stop after the shorter one does not have any elements left. That's why you are missing 2 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop works as long as there is something in *both* lists. This means that if one list has 6 items and the other 8 items, the `while` will run for 6 iterations. When it finishes with the 6th element of each list, the shorter list's `hasNext()` is going to become `false` and your loop will terminate.

To solve this, after your while loop, you should check which of the iterators still returns true for `hasNext()` (if any), and then add the items from that iterator - only from that iterator - to your `list3`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your condition :

```
itr.hasNext() & itr2.hasNext()
```

when you have iterated itr to its fifth element, then while loop exits. So the last elements of list2 are not iterated.

Note also that you should use operator "||" instead of "|" and "&&" instead of "&".

Answer (score 0):

You have 5 entries in one list, and 7 entries in the second list.

Your code test for both iterators having more values using an "&". When the shorter list is consumed, the program exits the main loop and it does not check for values left in one list or the other. It only works when the two lists have the same number of entries.

You **could** have another loop to see if there are left-over values in list 1, then check for left-over values in list 2.